# 2D Array 4x4 matrix additionin the same matrix in C++

Tags: multidimensional-array

print the value of row column and diagonal value in a 4x4 matrix in which you have to enter the value int the 3x3 matrix in the last row and column you have to print values of row column and diagonal
in C++

when you input the value of 3x3 matrix in the last row and column you have to print the value of row column and diagonal